# Is there a way to list the names of folders in firebase cloud storage and display them in flutter (e.g. List view)

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-storage

Let's say your files are structured like this: folder then a list of subfolders, how would you access the names of those subfolders and maybe display them in a listview. I have tried "result.prefixes" but am having trouble implementing it. Any leads or resources will be appreciated.

So @Dabbel I tried what you suggested and did this. Correct where i am wrong, right now i'm stuck at "lateinitializationerror field 'listResult' has not been initialized". Below is my code:
The models file:

```
class FirebaseFolder {
  final Reference ref;
  final String name;
  final String url;

  const FirebaseFolder({
    required this.ref,
    required this.name,
    required this.url,
  });
}
```

The screen code:

```
class DashBoard extends StatefulWidget {
  const DashBoard({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<DashBoard> createState() => _DashBoardState();
}

class _DashBoardState extends State<DashBoard> {
  late List<String> folderYear = [];
  late Future<List<FirebaseFolder>> listResult;


  @override
  void initState() async{
    super.initState();
   await getFolders();
    }
  Future<List<String>> getFolders() async {
    final storageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child("front end");
    final listResult = await storageRef.listAll();
    for (var prefix in listResult.prefixes) {
      folderYear.add(prefix.name);
    }
    return folderYear;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: kAppBar('DashBoard'),
      body: FutureBuilder<List<FirebaseFolder>>(
        //future: futureFiles,
        future: listResult,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
            case ConnectionState.waiting:
              return const Center(
                child: spinkitLines,
              );
            default:
              // final files = snapshot.data;
              final folders = snapshot.data;
              return Column(
                children: [
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 30.0,
                  ),
                  const Center(
                    child: Text(
                      'Tap to choose semester',
                      style: kPlaceholderStyle,
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 30,
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: folderYear.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        final folder = folders![index];
                        return Container(
                          height: 80,
                          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                            boxShadow: [
                              BoxShadow(
                                  color: Color.fromARGB(75, 0, 0, 0),
                                  blurRadius: 4,
                                  spreadRadius: 0,
                                  offset: Offset(0, 4))
                            ],
                          ),
                          child: Center(
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                              child: Text(
                                folder.name,
                                style: kCardTitleStyle,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Does this work?

```dart
final storageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child("front end");
final listResult = await storageRef.listAll();

// for (var prefix in listResult.prefixes) {
  // The prefixes under storageRef.
  // You can call listAll() recursively on them.
// }

for (var item in listResult.items) {
  // The items under storageRef.
}
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/flutter/list-files